# How to access localStorage in extension background page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extension that sets a string value in JavaScript localStorage in a content script. I have tested that it is being set by grabbing it and displaying it. While on the same page after it has loaded I can still access the stored string in the javascript console. If I go to any other tabs js console or  when I try to access it in my other extensions background page(After the browser action has been clicked) it is returning null.

extension 1 contentscript.js

```
embeded.addEventListener
(
 "message",
 function(message)
 {
  localStorage.setItem("pdf", message.data);
  loadPDF(message.data);
 },
 false
);
```

extension 2 background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (tab.url.substr(tab.url.length - 4) === ".pdf")
  {    
    if (localStorage.getItem("pdf") !== null)
    {
      alert("boomy"); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Wait, wait, two _separate_ extensions?

Comment: Out of interest - why two separate extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` is shared among extension pages (background, options, popup), but **not** content scripts. **And most certainly not shared between 2 extensions!**

<s>You have two-and-a-half options.</s> With 2 separate extensions, only one option.

---

**Option one: rely on messaging.**

When you need to pass some value between background and content script, you can do so with messaging. Works especially well if you only need to pass it in one direction.

*contentscript.js:*

```
embeded.addEventListener(
  "message",
  function(message)
  {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionTwoId, {pdf: message.data});
    loadPDF(message.data);
  },
  false
);
```

*background.js:*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(sender.id !== extenstionOneId) return;
    if(message.pdf) localStorage.setItem("pdf", message.pdf);
  }
);

/* ... */
```

---

**<s>Option two: `chrome.storage`.</s>** Not applicable between 2 extensions.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out.I was under the impression that javascript local storage would be available anywhere in the browser. My only issue with your code is in the content script. Would I have access to chrome.runtime.sendmessage in the content script?

Comment: Yes, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is one of the few things content scripts can call. `localStorage` is local to a certain context; i.e. one `localStorage` per hostname. It's not one big box everyone can use.

Comment: Think about it, it localStorage behaved like you want, a site could overwrite other site storage by using the same key. Impossible.