# Content script message handler not being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have **two Chrome extensions** and in one I need to receive a message in a content script. The other extension is sending a message in its background page. I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245334/chrome-extension-sendmessage-from-background-to-content-script-doesnt-work) but it did not work.

I changed `.extension` to `.runtime` in the listener and it still does not work. Here's the code:

extension 1, contentscript.js (this is not being fired)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("contentscript");
  if(sender.id !== "iknbmfmkhcilpbkobjafdhaloffobdbe") 
    return;
  if (document.getElementById("status").innerHTML === "1")
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

extension 2, background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {pdf: "You a pdf?"}, function(response) {alert(response.farewell);});  
  });
});
```

Comment: Usually, the background page is loaded before a tab exists. So, when you put `chrome.tabs.query` in the background page, then the result is that no tabs are matched. What are you trying to achieve with message passing?

Comment: Sorry. It is in a browser action so the tabs would be loaded at that point. I have tested it and it is sending the message out to the currently opened tab. It's not being received though.

Comment: Remove `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){` and `});`, and replace `tabs[0].id` with `tab.id`. And remove `if(sender.id !== "iknbmfmkhcilpbkobjafdhaloffobdbe") return;`

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected/23895822#23895822) explains your problem.

Comment: That is not the issue though I will remove the tab query because it is not needed. The listener in the content script is not being called so the senders id would not be the issue either.

Comment: Xan I don't think that is the issue. My content script would be injected before the browser action is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You really should put in **HUGE BOLD LETTERS** that your question is about two separate extensions.

What you're trying to achieve is impossible, as [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) does not support cross-extension messaging. This effectively means that content scripts can only be messaged by parent extension.

To achieve what you want, you need Extension 1's background page to act like a proxy:

```
// Extension 1, background
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(sender.id != extensionTwoId) return;
  if(message.tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.tabId, message, function(response){
      sendResponse(response);
    });
    return true; // Required if sendResponse will be called asynchronously
  } else {
    // It's not a message to be routed to a tab
  }
}
```

and

```
// Extension 2, background
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    extensionOneId,
    {tabId: tab.id, pdf: "You a pdf?"},
    function(response) {alert(response.farewell);}
  );
});
```

Comment: You [never answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836198/how-to-access-localstorage-in-extension-background-page) why on Earth you need two separate extensions..

Comment: The first is a native client extension and I was told by one of the senior programmers that you are not able to have browser/page actions along with them. Thanks for the answer. I thought it may have been an issue because of two extensions. I'll try your answer then upvote and check if it works.